# Jenkins on windows - Matrix-based security - not available

Tags: jenkins

I installed Jenkins on windows. Under "Configure global security" I don't find Matrix-based security option. is there a way i can enable that option? or it comes with a plugin?

thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's [Matrix Authorization Strategy](https://plugins.jenkins.io/matrix-auth/) plugin.

Also consider [Role-based Authorization Strategy](https://plugins.jenkins.io/role-strategy/) and [Folder-based Authorization Strategy](https://plugins.jenkins.io/folder-auth/) plugins as alternatives.

Comment: YW. Care to mark as answered and  upvote?

Comment: I don't have privilege to do that yet. thank you

Comment: it says I need 15 reputations